# MetadataService.cls, How can I filter the Metadata List based on the Last Modified Date?

Tags: soap-api, metadata

My requirement is that I need to display org metadata components (like Objects, Apex Classes, VF Pages, Record Types, Profiles, Permission Sets, Custom Object, Custom Fields, Custom Label ...etc) on my VF page. Thanks to @[salesforce-sas](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/70823/salesforce-sas) I came to know that I can use MetadataService.cls to get all this info.
Source : https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

But is it possible to filter the List of metadata by its Last Modified date? I mean to say I need the list of all Metadata which for which the last modified date is greater than last month

Does anybody have any idea regarding this? Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks
Nirav

Answer (score 1):

The Metadata API does not support queries. You would have to iterate through the returned metadata and filter it manually via Apex logic.

The Metadata API [`RetrieveResult`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieveresult.htm) does include `FileProperties` entries, with the values `lastModifiedById`, `lastModifiedByName`, and `lastModifiedByDate`.

While the Tooling API allows queries, many Tooling API objects don't expose a last modified date.